# CLASSIC ASP: INSERTING A RECORD

Tags: database, asp-classic, insert, record

First my apologizes for my poor english.
I'm trying insert a new record in a table (tblComentarios)

This is the code i'm using

```
conn.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"

conn.Open "C:\Users\VilaNova\Documents\aspirador\guestbook.mdb"

sql = "INSERT INTO tblComentarios (nome,comentario) "

sql = sql & "VALUES ('john', 'good job');"

on error resume next

conn.Execute sql, recaffected

if error <> 0 then

   response.write "No permissions!"

else

   response.write "added record!"

end if
```

When i execute the code i get no errors and i get the message "added record"
But, when i open de database and see the table's contents there is no
record with the values 'john' and 'good job'

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing `error` with [`Err.Number`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t7981hw%28VS.84%29.aspx):

```
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
```

My guess is that you don't have [`Option Explicit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28VS.84%29.aspx) turned on, so `error` is implicitly created as a new variable with its value set to `Empty`.  `Empty` is converted to 0 for the sake of comparison, so there appears to be no error.

(As an aside, if my guess is correct, you really should include `Option Explicit` as the first line of every script you write, and get in the habit of explicitly declaring your variables with `Dim`.)

Comment: Thank you! with Err.Number the program give the right output: No permissions! But how a solve this permission problem? Thx for the advice option explicit.

Comment: @informatica I wrote a detailed guide a while back, you can see it [here](http://forums.aspfree.com/asp-development-5/setting-permissions-to-access-database-step-by-step-guide-96087.html) - good luck!

Comment: Thanks, Shadow Wizard. I follow your guide and i can delete records and alter records but no insert new records. Very strange!